# How to assign colors according to a index in d3.js?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to get a color according to a metricValue variable (an integer) but the code below is returning the same color #1f77b4. What am I doing wrong?

```
function getColorForNode(d) {
    var p=d3.scale.category10();
    var metricValue = metrics.getScore(d.id)
    return(p(metricValue)); // Returns the same color independently of metricValue
}
```

Comment: It should work like that. Are you sure that `metricValue` is different between calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is related to the fact that no domain was specified for this ordinal scale.

It is true that you don't need to specify a domain for ordinal scales as described in the docs (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-ordinal_domain). In that case it will automatically build a domain on the fly while you are using the scale. It keeps track of that domain in the scale instance.

The problem is that in your case you create a new scale instance for each call to getColorForNode. So, there is no persistent domain. Every time it starts from scratch building a domain and it will output the first range value: #1f77b4.

So, there are basically two solutions:

Option 1: keep the scale instance construction outside the function

```
var p = d3.scale.category10();
function getColorForNode(d) {
  var metricValue = metrics.getScore(d.id);
  return p(metricValue);
}
```

Option 2: explicitly specify a domain

```
function getColorForNode(d) {
  var p = d3.scale.category10().domain(d3.range(10));
  var metricValue = metrics.getScore(d.id);
  return p(metricValue);
}
```

Comment: That was it! It restarted the domain at each execution, thanks for the explanation